# Wrong Response From Ajax Request using remote : true in rails 4, jquery-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a cart which add line items using ajax request.Suppose I click “A” then it show “A” and “A” in cart instead of “A”. Line item stores in database properly.
When I refresh the page it shows me the proper result “A” (without duplication).

Here is the cart button erb code

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true %>
```

Here is the create.js.erb file

```
$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript render(@cart) %>");
```

_line_item.html.erb

```
<tr>
    <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
    <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
    <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>
```

Summery is that, Why I'm getting last click item duplicate on ajax request response though I'm getting proper cart when I refresh the page (without any duplicate record)?

I’m new in rails. Am I missing something? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar code, but try to remove the class first, then append the new information in two steps.

In create.js.erb

```
$('#cart').empty();
$('#cart').append("<%= j render(@cart) %>");
```

Comment: it's not working, issue still exist.. however thanks for response :)

Comment: What browser are you using? Try using Chrome Developer Console for debugging the js request. Also, check your server and see how the response is being handled -- you should be looking for a line this: Processing by XYZController#create as JS